# installing issues for SciPy on Mac

Tags: python, macos, scipy

Installing issues for scipyp on Mac.

My Mac is 10.8, gcc is 4.2.1, gfortran is GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.2.1.

After I downloaded the package and typed `sudo python setup.py build`,
then it will output:

```
Could not locate executable f95
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
customize IBMFCompiler
Could not locate executable xlf90
Could not locate executable xlf
customize IntelFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_clib
building 'arpack_scipy' library
compiling C sources
C compiler: clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe

compile options: '-Iscipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c'
clang: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
In file included from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:24:10: fatal error: 'vImage/vImage.h' file not found
#include <vImage/vImage.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
In file included from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:24:10: fatal error: 'vImage/vImage.h' file not found
#include <vImage/vImage.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: Command "clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Iscipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I don't know why, can anyone explain this?

When I use `sudo pip install scipy` then the output is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:24:10: fatal error: 'vImage/vImage.h' file not found

#include <vImage/vImage.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

In file included from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:24:10: fatal error: 'vImage/vImage.h' file not found

#include <vImage/vImage.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: Command "clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Iscipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.o" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/Users/hadoop/Downloads/src/scipy/setup.py'; exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps failed with error code 1 in /Users/hadoop/Downloads/src/scipy
```

Comment: looks like the script uses clang instead of gcc.

Comment: Do you install "Command line tools" in Xcode property?

Comment: How did you install gcc and gfortran?

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://charlesmartinreid.com/wiki/Scipy_vImage.h_Problem)

To summarize, try

```
CFLAGS="-DVIMAGE_H" python setup.py build
```